# How does the clock() function in <ctime> access the system clock?

Tags: c++, c, system-calls, ctime

I'm using an STM32 microcontroller with minimal libraries attached. I'd like to use the `clock()` function from `<ctime>` (and potentially the new `std::chrono`) but I'm stuck at `clock()` returning -1.

This isn't surprising, since I don't expect the libraries in `gcc-arm-none-eabi` to know the peripheral layout of my microcontroller.

How do I tell `clock` where it gets its tick count from? Can I simply redeclare it, or is there a lower-level function that I need to implement?

Comment: [You might find this helpful.](https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/blob/master/lib/stm32/timer.c)

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm not so much asking _"how do I get the system clock?"_ as I am _"Given I can get the system clock, how do I link it with the `time.h` header?"_

Comment: In this case: you have to re-implement the `clock()` function.

Comment: @H2CO3: So it's not like `putchar()`, where you actually have to implement `_write`?

Comment: You implement it however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normally part of the job of porting a libc implementation to a new platform. When you compile a copy of glibc or newlib (the two most popular implementations of the C standard library) you have to provide a series of stub methods, one of these will be providing the time. `gcc-arm-none-eabi` is a target predefined in newlib that implements a lot of these stubs, but not the ones for getting the time, because like you said these are application specific.

The best thing to do would be to build the toolchain yourself, implementing this method. You can follow the instructions [here](http://www.kunen.org/uC/gnu_tool.html), but just before you build newlib edit the target to fill in this stub. A good reference to implementing the stubs is available [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib).

Alternatively you could implement your own `clock` function directly, when you link your application it will prefer your version over the one in the library. Be warned, however, this means that anything in the library that calls `clock` will still call the broken library version, so you may need to reimplement a lot of functions.

Comment: Thanks. `times` is the function name I was looking for. I'm assuming that the `libnosys.a` library I'm linking delegates that call to `_times`?

Comment: I think `libnosys.a` implements `times` as failing. What you probably want is to use `libgloss` rather than using `libnosys.a`, filling in whatever stubs you can.

Comment: No, defining `_times` without any toolchain recompilation did the trick. Thanks for the links.